# How should I efficiently add to an array from a Svelte store subscription?

Tags: javascript, arrays, websocket, svelte, svelte-store

I'd like to have objects added to an array in a component each time a subscribed store gets updated. In this case, the store is receiving data from a WebSocket, and I ultimately want to plot the last `N` datapoints that I've received (`N=1000` for example).

The store is defined in `socket.js`:

```
import { readable } from 'svelte/store';

export const datastream = readable([], set => {
  let socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8765")
  let data = [];

  socket.onmessage = function (event) {
    let { time, value } = JSON.parse(event.data);

    // update the data array
    // TODO: set a max buffer size
    data = [...data, {"time": time, "value": value}];

    // set the new data as store value
    set(data)
  }
})
```

I then have a `Chart.svelte` component which should a) plot the last `N` points (implementation not shown), b) update each time my store subscription callback occurs. The catch here is that I may need to do some minor conversion/preprocessing on the incoming WebSocket data. In my `Chart.svelte` we have (omitted the plotting stuff for brevity):

```
<script>
  ...
  import { datastream } from './socket.js';

  export let plot_data;

  const unsubscribe = datastream.subscribe(data => {
    plot_data = []
    for (let datum of data) {
      plot_data = [...plot_data, {x: datum.time, y: datum.value}]
    }
  });

  $: {...
      some stuff that sets up plotting
  ...}
</script>

<div class='my-chart'>
    ...(plot_data)
</div>
```

My question is; is this the best way to do this? I think it's not - It works, but I've got a duplicate of the array of data in the `datastream` store, and each time I get a new value, I completely rebuild the `plot_data` array.

I had attempted to do this with only the most recent data point subscribed in the store, but I couldn't figure out how to capture the store update and thereby force a new entry into the `plot_data` array (and thus, refresh the plot).

Comment: I think it's the right idea to save the latest N points of data in the store - this allows you to unmount & remount your chart component and not lose any data in the process, which you wouldn't be able to do if the store only held the latest single data point. However, I do not understand *why* you are rebuilding the entire data array in the component, can you please explain?

Comment: In this case, my store object looks like `{"time": "20:03:24", "value": 2.103}`, but to put it into the plot, I want to construct an object that reflects the required inputs for the plot object (i.e. `{x: value, y: value}`). In general, I may have to manipulate the object values in some way (i.e. format a timestamp string). 

In other words, I can't feed the store straight into the chart, as is. I couldn't figure out how to do this without the for loop.

Comment: I see your point now, I foolishly used a for loop, when I should have been using "push" to a top level defined array `plot_data`. Then I can manipulate the incoming data point as required and add it to the array... however, to trigger an update, I have to then do `plot_data = plot_data`... I suppose this is more efficient than the for loop.

Comment: I think even a simple reactive rule with a `map` would have done the trick. Something like `$: plot_data = $datastream.map(point => ({ x: point.time, y: point.value }))`. This will also trigger a re-render every time your store updates. Or even better, anticipate the conversion in your store, and format the data accordingly: `data = [...data, {x: time, y: value}]`, and directly use `{$datastream}` in your plot (which will also trigger a re-render with every store update).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

See this repl: [receive updates in batches](https://svelte.dev/repl/dfb1ce12042a440ea077e6e395d3c770?version=3.35.0)

But use this store for your use:

```
let socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8765")

const datastream = readable(null, set => {
  socket.onmessage = function (event) {
   set ({ time, value } = JSON.parse(event.data));
  };
});
```

Comment: This is basically it, as mentioned in the comment to @ThomasHennes, the push was what I should have done in the first place. I'll have to play around with using a derived store - I'm not sure that's necessary here or if that will be more efficient in terms of data/memory. Accepting this as it solved the original question.